# Can I render images on video tag of WebRTC

Tags: javascript, webrtc

I want to render image objects on HTML's video tag of WebRTC.
Because I want to create a game using WebRTC.

For example, I have been rendering by my smart phone's camera on video tag  of website.
In the HTML video tag, images of the camera of the smartphone and images of the treasure box are shown.
And I tap the treasure box, get some point.

Can I do this?

I think, I have to use canvas tag.

In my opinion, this flow:
smart phone's camera -> hidden video tag -> render canvas tag images and videos

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<video>` tag is the most visually gifted HTML element ever made. If you use just the `poster` attribute, it will render any image better than an `<img>` tag. In the following demo is a resizable `<video>` tag wrapped in a resizable `<div>`. 100% responsive. No need for a `<picture>` tag and all of the markup clutter that comes with it. The scrollbar is just for demo purposes so that the resize is easier to use (which you probably wouldn't need in production).

### Demo

```css
.rsz {
  resize: both;
  overflow:scroll;
}

.frame {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.vid {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class='frame rsz'>
  <video class='vid rz' poster='http://diarioveaonline.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/lovable-images-for-desktop-wallpapers-3.jpg'></video>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I was very surprised by the magnitude of video tags!
However, Can I render movie with picture in video tags?

Comment: Yes, the `poster` attribute maintains the image and shows it when the video is at an idle state like ended or after load, *but not when paused*. Essentially, 1. when playing or seeking the poster is hidden, 2. when video is paused the poster is hidden. 3. if the video ends, loads, or stops (basically `currentTime=0`), the poster is revealed.

Comment: Oh, I see!
Thank you very much!!

Comment: No problem, happy coding.